# How to get variable from one class in another class?

Tags: php, class, oop

I have 2 classes: `User` and `Answer`

I define in the class User that the name is "Peter"

how can I get the name defined in the `User` instance inside the `Answer` instance?

```php
$user= new User(); 
$user->name = "Peter";      


$answer = new Answer(); 
echo $answer->getListAnswer(); //how can I get the name of the User (Peter) in the function getListAnswer() in the Class Answer?
```

Comment: With Dependency Injection

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm or inversion :p or by just creating instances .. but inversion/injection is cleaner fo' sho

Answer (score 4):

Inject the `User` instance into the `Answer` instance. Like this, for example:

```
class Answer
   private $user;

   public function __construct(User $user) {
      $this->user = $user;
   }

   public function getListAnswer() {
      $userName = $this->user->name;

      // rest of your method.
      // Use $userName where you need it.
   }
}
```

First you create your `User` object as usual:

```
$user       = new User(); 
$user->name = "Peter";
```

In the constructor for `Answer` we declared that it needs (depends on) a `User` object. So you pass the user object you just created to instantiate a new `Answer`:

```
$answer = new Answer($user); 
echo $answer->getListAnswer();
```

Answer (score -3):

Well I'm not much sure of it, but if you try and define your variable scope with "global " in the Answer class,it might make some difference

Comment: global is hardly every the answer

Comment: @treyBake, the referencing the global $user, with the method, may be _a_ solution, but likely not the recommended one.

Comment: GLOBALS hurt your script. There is a very good reason why you have to declare them explicitly. Your function should accept parameters and return values without any side effects